# Power settings location?

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, battery

I have Xubuntu 14.04 and I am running it on an EeePC. Where in the world are my power settings? I've looked everywhere. I found this in my files, but I don't know how to open/use/install it.

/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/xfce4-power-manager.mo

Answer (score 0):

.mo files are commonly compiled files for the translation of an application, there are no  settings stored.

If you are looking for the settings of the xfce4-power-manager you should find it here:

```
$HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-power-manager.xml
```

But its better to use the GUI ( run in a terminal `xfce4-power-manager-settings`) to change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Click to the

> Power settings

under the

> System settings

that's all.